# passing variables not working on a new tab

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to open a new tab with a specific url with variables on it but the variables are not passed on the second tab. please help me with this .  Heres my code.

```
<?php
    $type= $_GET['type'];
    $brochure_id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql1 = "SELECT * from business_type WHERE business_id = '$type'";
    $q1= $conn->query($sql1);
    $q1->setFetchMode (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $location=" ";

        while($r1 = $q1->fetch())
        { 
            if($r1['business_type'] == "Hotel"){
                $location ="hotel.php";

            }
            else if($r1['business_type'] == "Restaurant"){
                $location ="restaurant.php";
            }
            else if($r1['business_type'] == "Resort"){
                $location ="resort.php";
            }
            else if($r1['business_type'] == "Spa"){
                $location ="spa.php";
            }
            else if($r1['business_type'] == "Entertainment"){
                $location ="entertainment.php";
            }
        }

    echo "<a  href='search-result-page-" . $location . "'?id='" . $brochure_id ."'' target='_blank' style='text-decoration: none'  >

    <div style='width: 260px; min-height: 30px; background-color:  rgba(180,180,180,0.5); position: absolute; z-index: 1000; font-size: 17px; padding: 5px; color: black'>" . $r['business_name'] . "</div>
    <img src='". $r['display_pic'] ."' width='260px' height='150px' />
    </a>
    </td>";

        if($maxcol==$column){
                echo "</tr>";
                $column=0;
                }
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: From where you're getting `$brochure_id`? Also, Look at your image tag. Why do you have `<?php` and `?>` tags, you are already inside `echo`?

Comment: it's already declared on top of my code. i just did not include some parts of my code cause it would be very long

Comment: Do `ctrl+u`(or `cmd+u` on Mac) to see the source code, and check what you have there in anchor and image tags.

Comment: `target='blank'` that's an outright typo. It should read as `target='_blank'`

Comment: [Read/reload this comment again...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523354/passing-variables-not-working-on-a-new-tab#comment70252749_41523354); you're still using invalid syntax and is more than likely the root of this problem.

Comment: Your qoutes are incorrect on the link commandline

Comment: @fred i change my blank to _blank still not working

Comment: correct my code so i could see were i did wrong

Comment: edit your question again as to what you're now using. Some may very well submit answers based on that; believe me. If that is failing you, then you may have syntax errors; check for them.

Comment: help me please. the due for my project is fast approaching

Comment: someone stated that your quotes are incorrect; view your html source, use error reporting, var_dump and if there is any relevance to `?id` being passed to your next page, then make sure that GET array is correct. There isn't anything else I can add to this.

Comment: Consider deleting your obsolete comments (about edits made to the code) that add nothing to the discussion currently, as they only clutter the topic.